# R function to compare two lists against each other for correction

Tags: r, vector, filtering

Lets say I have two vectors for example:

```
a <- c(1,2,2.1,2.2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
b <- c(0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,7.6,7.7,8.5)
```

Filter the two vectors with a function:

```
a_corrected_by_b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
b_corrected_by_a <- c(0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5)
```

So when you subtract the two lists from each other you get:

```
c <- (a_corrected_by_b - b_corrected_by_a)
#((1-0.5), (2-1.5), (3-2.5), (4-3.5), (5-4.5), (6-5.5), (7-6.5), (8-7.7), (9-8.5))
```

I just cant figure out how to filter both of the vectors against each other so you can get two vectors that can subtract from each other properly.

There should be an `a` vector value in between each `b` vector value and there should be a `b` vector value in between each `a` vector value.

It should also be the closest value to the value in either list as well. So is there any function that can run through both vectors and remove the unnecessary values? So the two vectors can be the same length and have the proper values to subtract from each other.

Comment: How do you decide which value of, say `a`, lies between two values of `b` when there multiple values? E.g. in `a` `2,2.1,2.2` lie between `1.5,2.5` from `b`

Comment: @markus the closest value so for example, 1.5 in list b would correlate to 2 in list a. and 2.5 in list b would correlate to 3 in list a. Also the number in list a should always be larger than the number in list b when compared.

Comment: @ChuckP I do want to do that, however there is some nuance with it. For example list a[1] could be 5 and b[1] could be 3 and that would be ok to subtract. But a[6] could be 12 and b[6] could be 17 this would not be ok.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to compare every number from `a` to every number from `b`, and keep any member of `a` which is the smallest member of the set that exceeds one of the members of `b`. If a single member of `a` meets this criterion for multiple values of `b`, you only include the highest value of `b` among the matches.

It really has to be done this way because if you allow members of `a` to be matched to members of `b` that are either lower *or* higher, then the matching becomes undecidable and ill defined.

You can achieve this using `outer` and `unique`:

```
correct <- function(a, b)
{
  d <- outer(a, b, `-`)
  d[d < 0] <- NA
  data.frame(a_corrected_by_b = a[unlist(unique(apply(d, 2, which.min)))],
             b_corrected_by_a = b[unlist(unique(apply(d, 1, which.min)))])
}
```

So for example:

```
correct(a, b)
#>   a_corrected_by_b b_corrected_by_a
#> 1                1              0.5
#> 2                2              1.5
#> 3                3              2.5
#> 4                4              3.5
#> 5                5              4.5
#> 6                6              5.5
#> 7                7              6.5
#> 8                8              7.7
#> 9                9              8.5
```

Note there are some sequences that won't "correct" by this method, for example if each member of `b` is higher than each member of `a`.

Also, it is not symmetrical, since one of the two sets has to take precedence in the event of ties, so `correct(a, b)` will be different from `correct(b, a)`, though they will both give valid solutions. This is because the problem as stated does not always have a unique solution.